# What is the format of the string displayed when previewing a binary file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a file I want to download that is displayed as a preview in a webview. I can access the html content of the webview from outside of it. I would like to save the file that is being previewed as a binary file. Given `document.body.innerHTML`, is there any way to recover the binary data or I need the original data from the request?

The preview looks something like this
[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: agree with @phuzi. You have to know in wich format are the original data and then try to convert/display it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"What is the format of the string that is being displayed"* - The browser has done it's best to render the binary data as if it was a unicode encoded string, probably UTF-8.

It's possible/likely that here are byte sequences that do not match up to valid unicode characters, depending on the exact encoding used. This will cause those sequences to be replaced by a unicode replacement character preventing the original binary data from being recoverable from the preview.

Your best bet bet would be to retreive the original data.

Comment: I ended up getting the data from the request directly. Thanks for the clarification! :)